# Cost of producing posters in World War I

Tags: europe, british-empire, world-war-one

I know that a lot of posters were printed out during World War I, but am confused by the cost for the government to produce all these. A google search normally yields some results, but this time it is very confusing:  [Google on the cost of printing posters](https://www.google.co.uk/#safe=active&hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=Cost+of+printing+posters+in+ww1&oq=Cost+of+printing+posters+in+ww1&gs_l=hp.3...513.16889.0.17327.35.23.3.9.9.0.169.1818.20j3.23.0...0.0...1c.1.12.psy-ab.kw1Zg8Cpmkg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.45960087,d.d2k&fp=b8c1ad4883f89980&biw=1600&bih=799) I have also been unable to find the number of posters printed out.

Comment: I'd start by finding out which firms actually did the printing and then perhaps looking up their archives.

Comment: Any idea where to start?

Comment: Since you are asking all this WW 1 propaganda/poster-related questions I'd be interested to hear a bit more about the context: are you researching the period for some specific reason or task? Just curious.